# Looking for a function with $f(0) = 0$, $f'(0) = 1$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$

Tags: functions

I'm looking for a monotonic, continuous function function with these properties:

$$f(0) = 0$$
$$f'(0) = 1$$
$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$$

I also need a coefficient that allows me to configure the *speed* at which it reaches 1.

I've got the feeling that there is a well-known function that I am looking for but my brain just refuses to give it to me right now.

Comment: What is "sine-like" supposed to mean? What about $f(t)=\frac2\pi\arctan(\frac\pi2 t)$? Or in fact, what about $f(t)=\min\{t,1\}$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I replaced *sine-like* with *continuous*. Your proposed function is fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "the *speed* at which it reaches $1$"?

Comment: @CameronBuie Assume that $x$ is a time-variable (should have named it $t$). So a coefficient to adjust for which x $f'(x) < 0.01$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This might make things easier. Take any function such that $f(0)=0, f'(0)=1$. Then

$$\frac{f(x)}{1+f(x)}$$

automatically satisfies both of these and your third requirement if $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty$. It's also monotonically increasing when your original function is. If you have any single function $g$ such that $g(x)=0, g'(x)=1$, then $\frac 1n g(nx)$ will also have these properties, allowing you to generate a family of functions. For example, if we take $f(x)=\sinh(x)$, then our family of functions is $\frac 1n\sinh(nx)$ and our overall set of solutions is $$\frac{\sinh(nx)}{n+\sinh(nx)}$$

which you can verify have all of your needed properties and approach $1$ at varying rates. Plug in any increasing function with $f(x)=0$ and $f'(x)=1$ in place of $\sinh(x)$ and you'll have all the fine-tuning you need.

Answer (score 11):

Here are a variety of functions (taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function)!

[image]

Many of these types of equations can be parameterized to control rate of convergence. A simple way would be to paramaterize a combination of two of these functions e.g. $f(x) = ag_1(x) + (1-a)g_2(x)$, where $g_1,g_2$ are relatively "fast" or "slow" converging functions.

Answer (score 4):

$f(x) = 1-e^{-x}$ would seem to be a candidate.

Another one is

$$f(x) = 1-e^{-(e^x-1)}$$

In general:

$$f(x) =  1-e^{-g(x)}$$

where $g(0)=0$, $g'(0)=1$, and $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest $$f(x)=\frac{x\alpha}{x\alpha+1},\qquad\alpha>0.$$

Comment: How about you add a parameter $\alpha$ with the $x$'s so that you can satisfy the requirement about "how fast it approaches 1"?

Comment: @rschwieb: Thanks for suggestion. I've edited it in.

Comment: Err, heh, actually I was thinking $\alpha x$ would be a bit more predictable.

Comment: I'm not sure your parametrization satisfies the derivative requirement.

Comment: $$f'(x) = \frac{\alpha x^{\alpha-1}}{(x^{\alpha}+1)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{l l} x & x\le 1\\ 1 & x > 1\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Ok it doesn't have a parameter to adjust "speed"