# Looking for a function with $f(0) = 0$, $f'(0) = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$

Tags: functions

Similar to [Looking for a function with $f(0) = 0$, $f'(0) = 1$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379594/looking-for-a-function-with-f0-0-f0-1-and-lim-limits-x-to-infty)

I'm looking for a monotonic, continuous and differentiable function with these properties:

$$f(0) = 0$$
$$f'(0) = 0$$
$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$$

A coefficient is needed to configure the *speed* at which it reaches 1, or the actual shape of the curve

Could anyone give any advice? Thanks!

Comment: How about $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$?

Comment: Also $\tanh(x)^2$.

Comment: @Magma - did you mean $\tanh(x^2)$ ?

Comment: @AnuragA also, do you know anywhere can I plot these functions? I can manually plot them in python, but is there better approach?

Comment: @Henry That works too.

Comment: As soon as you have one such function $f(x)$, you can configure the speed by considering $f(ax)$ where $a > 0$.  When $a > 1$, $f(ax)$ will reach $1$ "faster".

Comment: @cqcn1991 you can try wolfram alpha.

Comment: @Gae.S. in that question we have $f'(0) = 1$.  In this question we require $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Ah, you are right.

Comment: None of $\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$, $\tanh(x)^2$, $\tanh(x^2)$ is monotonic as requested.  But I think $\tanh(x^3)$ or similarly $\frac{2}{\pi} \tan^{-1}(x^3)$ should work.

Comment: Do you want it to be monotonic for all real $x$, or just $x > 0$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Both is OK for my case. Since I can use f(|x|)  .

Comment: @Anurag Consider turning your comment into an answer

Comment: Not asked for, but a nice extension - $f(x) = \begin{cases} \operatorname{sgn}(x) e^{-1/x^2}, & x \ne 0 \\ 0, & x = 0 \end{cases}$ is $C^\infty$, monotonic, has $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for all $n$, and $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 1$.

Comment: Differentiability is a local property, what does $f'(0) = 0$, $f(0) = 0$ have to do with $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 1$ ?

Comment: But $f(|x|)$ will not be monotonic (unless it is constant).  If it's increasing for $x > 0$, it's decreasing for $x < 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am just putting out my comment as the answer.
Let
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}, & \text{ for } x \geq 0\\
0, & \text{ for } x <0.
\end{cases}
$$

Then $f(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=1$.
$$
f'(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}, & \text{ for } x \geq 0\\
0, & \text{ for } x <0.
\end{cases}
$$
Thus $f'(0)=0$. Furthermore, $f$ is non-decreasing over $\Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}0 & x<1\\ x-1 & x\in[1,2]\\ 1 & x>2 \end{cases}$$

edit: here is a differentiable answer,

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}0 & x<1\\ \frac{2}{9}(x-1)^2 & x\in[1,\frac{3}{2}]\\ -\frac{2}{9}(x-2)^2 & x\in[\frac{3}{2},2]\\ 1 & x>2 \end{cases}$$

Comment: I think this is not `continuous`, right?

Comment: @cqcn1991 it is continuous but not differentiable

Comment: It certainly is continuous. It's not differentiable.

Comment: OK, I'll edit my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about:
$$
f(x)= \left(
\frac{\arctan(x)}{\pi/2}
\right)^2
$$

Answer (score 0):

How about:

$$f(x) = \dfrac{x^3}{1+|x^3|}$$

$$f(0) = 0, f'(x) = \dfrac{3x^2}{\left(1+|x^3|\right)^2}, f'(0) = 0, \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 1$$

This seems to satisfy all of your conditions. Its derivative is continuous. It is monotonically increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Although the above answers are complete, here’s another function that you may like.

Let
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
1 - e^{-x^2}, & \text{ for } x \geq 0\\
e^{-x^2} - 1, & \text{ for } x <0.
\end{cases}
$$

Clearly, It is monotonous, $f(0) = 0$, $f’(0) = 0$, and, $lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 1$.

PS: This function is obtained by just an algebraic manipulation (really, adding constant 1) of a very famous curve.